# listener cycle callbacks

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

hello i hace problem this code :

ListenerCrud.php

```
<?php

namespace mio\mioBundle;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use mio\mioBundle\Entity\Log;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ListenerCrud{

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs){

        if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof Usuario){
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $log = new Log();
        $entityManager->persist($log);
        $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

config.yml :

```
listenercrud:
    class: mio\mioBundle\ListenerCrud
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate}
```

but no create log in database. help me please.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case $entityManager->persist() does not works because he can't be called in a preUpdate event.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

Maybe you can use the postUpdate event
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist

Comment: then, how to save changes to the database if it is allowed flush in PreUpdate? I need save getOldValue($fieldName) in PostUpdate. thanks.